# Shutting down the server, when I configure SSL WAMP SERVER

Tags: ssl-certificate

I'm trying activate ssl cert, for https, I have an certificate and server.key and server.crs

My `httpd-vhosts` :

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:443>

    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/
    ServerName xxxxx.com

    SSLCertificateFile c:/wamp64/SSL/xxxxxx.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile c:/wamp64/SSL/mhdp.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile c:/wamp64/SSL/DigiCertCA.crt
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
#
```

My `httpd.cnf` :

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

but get this `apache-log` and `https://localhost` doesn't work.

```
[Tue Oct 03 17:03:28.136407 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 760:tid 324] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Oct 03 17:03:30.155811 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7896:tid 216] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Oct 03 17:03:30.171411 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 760:tid 324] AH00430: Parent: Child process 7896 exited successfully.
[Tue Oct 03 17:03:31.875814 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 3948:tid 324] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Oct 03 17:03:32.016215 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 3948:tid 324] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Oct 03 17:03:32.031815 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3948:tid 324] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 03 17:03:32.031815 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3948:tid 324] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  1 2016 11:43:51
[Tue Oct 03 17:03:32.031815 2017] [core:notice] [pid 3948:tid 324] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp64\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.23\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23'
[Tue Oct 03 17:03:32.031815 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3948:tid 324] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 14280
[Tue Oct 03 17:03:32.468616 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 14280:tid 216] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Oct 03 17:03:32.624616 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 14280:tid 216] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Oct 03 17:03:32.640216 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14280:tid 216] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

Answer (score 0):

The logs are not showing any error. But try to enable this in the httpd.conf file **mod_socache_shmcb**